# Bat script's remote path not working with "SET Profiles=\\%PC%\C$\Users"

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, remote-access, delete-file, user-profile

```
@ECHO OFF
:ProfilDeleter
SET /P PC=Enter Remote Ip/HostName (for Exit press M): 
if [%PC%]==[] cls && @echo you should fill && goto ProfilDeleter
if %PC%==m goto :Menu
if %PC%==M goto :Menu

SET /p NotToBeDeleted=Your UserName: 
cls
::HERE NOT WORKING
SET Profiles=\\%PC%\C$\Users

PushD "%Profiles%"
if /I Not "%CD%"=="%Profiles%" (ECHO. Unable to find %Profiles% exiting)&Pause&goto Menu
FOR /F "Delims=" %%I in ('Dir /AD /B ^|FindStr /I /V /C:"%NotToBeDeleted%" /C:"ADMINI~1" /C:"Public" /C:"Default" /C:"Administrator"') DO RD /Q /S "%%I"
PopD
pause
:Menu
Exit
```

I made batch in order to delete Remote User Profile Folders
But I can't run for Remote PCs? Where is the problem in the script?

Comment: _Not working_ has no diagnostic value. Please [edit] your question and add more details: error message(s), undesired behaviour etc. Try `Dir /AD /B` to see output and debug `Dir /AD /B | findstr ...` out of `for /F` command.

Comment: If I change  **SET Profiles=\\%PC%\C$\Users**   to    **SET Profiles=C:\Users** script works.

Comment: With **SET Profiles=\\%PC%\C$\Users** 
I get "Unable to find %Profiles% exiting" echo message?

Comment: Please note that [StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/) are not chat-like ones. Improve your question using [edit] link rather than posting comments. Add `ECHO ON` right before your `PUSHD` and  add `echo "%CD%"=="%Profiles%"` right after it (before `IF`).

Comment: I am getting the same error :(

Comment: I can't see _any error_ described in your question nor in comments. And again: please _improve your question_ using [edit] link rather than posting comments!

Comment: OK; thank you... I think I can not express my problem. I want to delete some remote user folders except two folders. And this script works well on my local pc but not working on Remote PCs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Pushd - UNC Network paths](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html):

> When a `UNC` path is specified, `PUSHD` will create a temporary drive
>   map and will then use that new drive.
>   The temporary drive letters
>   are allocated in reverse alphabetical order, so if `Z:` is free it
>   will be used first.

After `PushD "%Profiles%"`:

- `"%Profiles%"` would keep to be `"\\<PC or IP entered>\C$\Users"` but
- `"%CD%"` would resolve to something like `"Z:\Users"`

Change the script logic as follows (with some debugging `ECHO`s):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
:ProfilDeleter
SET /P "PC=Enter Remote Ip/HostName (for Exit press M): " 
if "%PC%"=="" (
  rem cls
  echo you should fill
  goto :ProfilDeleter
)
if /I "%PC%"=="m" goto :Menu

SET /p "NotToBeDeleted=Your UserName: "
if "%NotToBeDeleted%"=="" SET "NotToBeDeleted=%UserName%"  
rem cls
SET "Profiles=\\%PC%\C$\Users"

echo variables are set as follows:
echo       Profiles "%Profiles%"
echo             PC "%PC%"
echo NotToBeDeleted "%NotToBeDeleted%"
if exist "%profiles%" (
    PushD "%Profiles%"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
      echo CD after pushd "!CD!"
    ENDLOCAL
    rem next `FOR … DIR … |FINDSTR` command requires further debugging IMHO
    FOR /F "Delims=" %%I in ('
      Dir /AD /B ^|FindStr /I /V /C:"%NotToBeDeleted%" /C:"All users" /C:"Public" /C:"Default" /C:"Administrator"
    ') DO (
            rem remove `ECHO` from next line no sooner than debugged
            ECHO RD /Q /S "%%I"
          )
    PopD
) else (
    ECHO. Unable to find "%Profiles%" exiting
    Pause
    goto Menu
) 
:Menu
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Read [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php) article.

Comment: I managed to work it. But it is very very slow
Thank you @JosefZ